# Proper BASH piping syntax

Tags: bash

I'd like to do a one line bash command to ping a server, then send an email if it fails.

I was thinking it ought to look something like:

```
ping whatever.com || echo 'Subject: VPN Failed" | sendmail me@me.com
```

But my BASH skills are "growing" and I'm apparently missing something.  What would be the proper way of doing that?

Comment: You have the wrong closing quotation mark, `"` instead of `'`.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You started the string with single quote, ended it with double quote. They have to match.

Comment: Aside from the quote, I've avoided the construction you are using for concerns about readability / precedence.  Also, on some platforms, ping doesn't exit ( like -c ).

Comment: Thank you - stupid oversight on my part!

Comment: @Mark This is a perfectly valid use of `||`; the main concern is constructs like `a && b || c`, which will *not*, in general, do what you expect. (I.e., `c` will run if `b` fails, when the intent is for `c` to run only if `a` fails.) `||` is well defined to combine two pipelines into a single command list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed single/double quotes.

In addition, if you want to use instruction in case of failure, I recommend using the `!` and `&&` operators, which will allow you to perform several instructions.

For instance:

```
! ping whatever.com && echo "An error occured, system will send an e-mail" >&2 && echo "Subject: VPN Failed" |sendmail me@me.com
```

Comment: On Stackoverflow you can give [up-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to people's helpful answers to thank them.